# How to add comma formated labels for Y-axis in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Here is jsfiddle for reference,
I tried to work on this fiddle but I can not, any one of you can modify this fiddle and respond here??

Comment: Here is Jsfiddle Link : 

**http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/DXQSU**

Answer (score 2):

use the following option:

```
  Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
      thousandsSep: ','
    }
  });
```

Check the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/mydspL1v/):

```
$(function() {
  Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
      thousandsSep: ','
    }
  });

  $('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
      data: [123654, 785122, 105296, 4578963,4758932]
    }]
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please edit given jsfiddle with comma seperated format pleaseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee......

Comment: That example is just to export an image, what is exactly your final goal (image, interactive chart, ...)? please share more details to better assess your needs :)

Comment: I want to make comma separated Y-axis labels and custom sans serif pro regular font in given fiddle :  
 
jsfiddle.net/highcharts/DXQSU

Answer (score -2):

Add y axis label format in your code

```
  yAxis: {
    labels: {
      format: '{value:,.1f}'
    }
  }
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pandiyancool/qfyygpmb/

Comment: Hey but it is not showing comma when image gets generated, it is with space.